# Evaluating a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate this double integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\cos\ (\max \ \{x^3,y^{\frac{3}{2}} \} )\ dxdy$$

I have hint with me that this is to be done with help of Greens theorem but i dont know how to start it

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: In any case, start dividing the integration domain along the curve $x^3=y^{3/2}$.

Comment: in any case what do you mean by this . thanks pls be more specific i am kind of weak student in math

Comment: "In any case" is with or without Green.Your big problem is that $\max$ is a piecewise function. In *each* piece, $\max(\cdots)$ will be simply $x^3$ or $y^{3/2}$.

Comment: by piece u mean sides of square .?

Comment: i still coudnt see the solution

Comment: By piece I mean 2D piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: divide the integration domain along the curve $x^3=y^{3/2}$. In each subdomain the integrand is function of only *one* variable:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\cos(\max \{x^3,y^{\frac{3}{2}} \} )\,dxdy=
\iint_{D_1}\cos(x^3)\,dxdy+\iint_{D_2}\cos(y^{3/2})\,dxdy.
$$
Can you continue?

Comment: is d1 THE SIDE OF SQUARE FROM (O,O) TO (1,0) AND D2 FROM (1,0) TO (1,1) . IF YES then how come u have taken x^3 for former piece. thnx for help n sorry for being dumb

Comment: $D1$, $D2$ are **2D** chunks of the square. The *border* of $D1$ is the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ $\cup$ the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ $\cup$ the curve $x^3=y^{3/2}$ from $(1,1)$ to (0,0). When $(x,y)\in D_1$, $x^3\ge y^{3/2}$ and $\max(x^3,y^{3/2})=\cdots$

Comment: ok i have quite understodd you . u mean dividing square into two triangles u have written d1 for one of triangle and then evaluating region over triangles(both 1 by 1 ) . my final question is how can u say that for D1 x^3 > y^3/2 mathematically ! thanks a lot

Comment: (a) triangles with a non-straight side. (b) re-write $x^3=y^{3/2}$ as $y=\cdots$

Comment: can we check this by making graphs of x^3 and x^3/2 in d1 and see which is up amd that vl be maximum ? or is there another way

Comment: There is only *one* graph.

Comment: >graph is square only ..but im saying that there is max function involved and for region D1 what output vl max function gives how to find that is my question really

Comment: I mean the graph of $x^3=y^{3/2}$. About the inequality, a easier question: what happens above and below $y=x$? If you understand this, you will understand why $x^3\ge y^{3/2}$ in $D_1$.

Comment: Thanks below y=x x>y and then radicals vl take care of rest stuff . thanks buddy